# Master Page Anchor tag Text to be written in a div on another page when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor

I have a very peculiar need in my application. I have a master page on which there are many  tags created and given the href attribute dynamically.

What I require is that when the user clicks on any of the  tags, its text must be captured and written in an already specified div in the referenced content page. How can this be achieved????

I've seen many articles but it has got me nowhere. I would really appreciate some kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to set the text of a div in the content page on click of the link in master page.
One way of doing this is as follows

Create an interface like below

```
public interface ITagable
{
    public string Tag { set; }

}
```

Implemente this interface in all the content page which needs the tag to be displayed

```
public partial class YourPage : System.Web.UI.Page,ITagable
{
   public string Tag
   {
      set 
      { 
            //set the value to your div
            this.tagDiv.InnertText = value; 
      }
   }
}
```

In the master page, on click event of the tag link set this property

```
protected void linkButtonTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton hyperLinkTag = sender as LinkButton;
    if (Page is ITagable)
        (Page as ITagable).Tag = hyperLinkTag.Text;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kiran Hegde. I appreciate your help, but I needed to do it from the master page itself without having to write any sort of code in the content page. I am glad to inform you that I solved my problem. Thanks for guiding me. Much appreciated.